# Need to click twice to update server - Angular2

Tags: javascript, json, rest, angular

I have a json that is not being update on the first time I click on the button that updates it. The button in question calls this function:

```
recusaProposta(){
    this.propostaService.atualizaDisputa(this.disputa)
    .subscribe(
      res => this.disputa.propostas_realizadas++,
      error => console.log(error)
    );
}
```

Now, at the first time I click on it nothing happens on the json but if I click on it again it does update the field I want (`disputa.propostas_realizadas`)

Here's the service:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Http, Headers, Response, RequestOptions} from '@angular/http';
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';
import {DisputaPropostaComponent} from './disputas-proposta.component';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class DisputaPropostaService{

    contato:Object[] = [];
    name: string;
    headers:Headers;
    url: string = 'http://localhost:3004/disputa';

    constructor(private http: Http){}

    atualizaDisputa (body:any): Observable<DisputaPropostaComponent[]>{
        let bodyString = JSON.stringify(body); // Stringify payload
        let headers      = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }); // ... Set content type to JSON
        let options       = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers }); // Create a request option
        return this.http.put(`${this.url}/${body['id']}`, body, options) // ...using post request
                         .map((res:Response) => res.json()) // ...and calling .json() on the response to return data
                         .catch((error:any) => Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Ocorreu um erro em nosso servidor, tente novamente mais tarde')); //...errors if any
    }
}
```

Can you guys help me? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that in your function you return disputa.propostas_realizadas before increasing it by 1. Replace your function with the code below and it should work.

```
recusaProposta(){
    this.propostaService.atualizaDisputa(this.disputa)
    .subscribe(
      res => ++this.disputa.propostas_realizadas,
      error => console.log(error)
    );
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but it still doesn't work :(, right after I click on the button I'm asking to print `disputa.propostas_realizadas` and this updates at first time but the json is not updated :(. Well, thanks anyway